# SQL Update query " Merchandise Detail - 001 " to " Product ID - 001 "

Tags: sql

I am wondering if anyone knows how to update the information like this

```
Merchandise Detail - 001
Merchandise Detail - 002 to
Merchandise Detail - 499
Merchandise Detail - 500
```

I want to update all the information at once to

```
Product ID - 001
Product ID - 002 to
Product ID - 499
Product ID - 500
```

Basically everything in front of " - Number " is the same.
Is there an update command I can do it? Thank you very much.

I am using PHPmyadmin.

Comment: i tried to click on it, but it said I need to have 15 reputation. I am not really sure how to increase it. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
update TableName set ColumnName=replace(ColumnName, 'Merchandise Detail', 'Product ID')
```

Add where clause if required!

Answer (score 1):

```
update your_table
set your_column = replace(your_column, 'Merchandise Detail', 'Product ID')
```

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL you could use

```
UPDATE your_table
SET your_field = REPLACE(your_field, 'Merchandise Detail', 'Product ID')
```